# Understanding the convergence of an optimiztion algorithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, convex-optimization

I have an optimization algorithm that solve a minimization problem. I did manage to find the convergence rate of the algorithm, but I want to undertand how to analyze it. I mean what does it mean if the convergence rate is a constant value?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the convergence rate of an algorithm?

Comment: What I understand about the convergence rate is how quickly can the sequence converges to some limiting value..

Comment: OK, but here we are talking about algorithms, not about sequences.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco OK, I think it is the same thing, it all about how quickly can the sequence that generated by the specific algorithm converges to the optimal value of the problem. Or what do you think?? –

Comment: Maybe you're right, but it really difficult to answer with too little and generic information. For instance, does your algorithm yield a sequence as output?

Comment: Yes it does yield a sequence, and I get the convergence of the output sequence to the optimal value is a constant value but I don't know how what does this mean..@Taroccoesbrocco

Comment: Did you look up, for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence?

Comment: Thanks, yes I have seen it. In my case I found that  the convergence rate defined by the  absolute value for the difference between the sequence that is generated by the algorithm and the optimal solution  represents the number of iterations. But I would like to know how many number of iterations for the algorithm to say the algorithm is  faster?@user550103